# How do I set up a Pi as a print server for a Canon LBP7010C?

Tags: printing

I would like to have a Raspberry Pi to act as a print server in order to share a USB printer on my home network.

The printer is a Canon iSenSYS LBP7010C (colour laserjet), drivers I am told are available online at Canon.

Would the RPi needs a fixed IP address as the printer port?

It would be running headless so it needs to reboot into Print Server mode if the power went off/on.

Comment: There is nothing special about the Pi in this regard, it's just like any other Linux box.  You should be able to find a better suited site for these questions.